# Error pages does not following content type/ format

Tags: symfony, twig

I followed this tutorial, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html, and have error.html.twig and error.json.twig within app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/

Even though the content type of the request is set to application/json, all errors default to the html version of the error page.

The format of the route is also defined:
http://symfonyinstall/api/v1/users.json

Request Header:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: chrome-extension: //rest-console-id
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko)           Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19
```

Response Header:

```
Status Code: 404
date: Sun, 29 Apr 2012 06:54:35 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
cache-control: no-cache
```

I'm out of ideas... and I really need a json version of the errors for my API to work...

Comment: It looks like we need a little more information to get to the root of your issue. If your have your template with the proper naming, in the proper file, Symfony should find it automatically. You should check to make sure that your error.json.twig template doesn't have any errors and that it is indeed properly named (trailing or leading spaces are valid on some filesystems and can be hard to see). In order to make things easier to debug, you may want to extend the default ExceptionController and see the output of Request::getRequestFormat() directly to see if your request is showing up as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same problem, and although your question is quite old and symfony bumped a few versions up since then, the problem is still relevant, so even if you don't need to know it any more, maybe somebody else will.

Your original problem was probaly caused by error described [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9988), but there wasn't much going on about it after initial post. Since then the entire codebase was updated, so while the same symptoms reappeared, the error is not related. I am posting it here because anybody looking for an answer these days will probably find this question (as I did :).

Even when returing `JsonResponse` directly form kernel exception handler, it will still have `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. This stumped me so much that I used netcat to make a manual request without any smart software in between, and it turns out that the response in such case has actually two different Content-Type headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
X-Debug-Token: 775c55
X-Debug-Token-Link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/_profiler/775c55
Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016 23:08:31 GMT
```

Now, double Content-Type header is not something you see everyday. It seems that this is implemented in `Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler` class that is only used in debug mode. In order to be as robust as possible, it first renders standard Symfony error page that describes thrown exception. Rendered content is not sent back directly, instead it leverages PHP's output buffering feature to buffer and store produced output. Then it attempts to produce custom error page from framework. In case this fails, previously prepared message is sent.

Output buffering however works only for message content, and not for headers - these are always sent directly. This problem only appears in debug environment, and unusual content types on error are only common in WebAPI, where debug mode is arguably of little use. This makes exposure surface relatively small, but if an application that offers both WebAPI and end-user interface needs to be tested, this might become a problem.

Solving this problem without modifying internal Symfony files doesn't seem possible. Output control sits deep within symfony kernel and doesn't offer any configuration. Anyway, I am not convinced of benefits of such solution. If anyone could explain to me what could have happened during custom exception handler that would make default handler useless in case it failed?
Maybe user code messing with ob_* functions?