# Symfony 2 error page response

Tags: json, symfony, twig, httpresponse

I have a SPA written in Angular used with a Symfony2 API. I want error responses like 500 to be retuned in json format rather than the HTML which according to the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) is supported out the box.

> For error pages, it first looks for a template for the given format and status code (like error404.json.twig);

I just cannot find anywhere that shows me how to explicitly specify that I want the json format. I thought having the request header 'Accept': 'application/json' was what it was talking about however that does not work as mentioned in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370354/error-pages-does-not-following-content-type-format.)

How can I have `throw new NotFoundHttpException('Could not find....');` return a json response opposed to the default HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set format in two ways:

1. `{_format}` placeholder in route's path,
2. In your controller call `$request->setRequestFormat('json')` method

---

```
routeName:
    path: /news/{id}/show.{_format}
    defaults:
        _controller: BundleName:Controller:method
        format: json
    requirements:
        _format: json|xml|html # you can remove xml & html, if you no have there formats
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that should be done in routing.yml. Ideally I want a way to do it with as little duplication as the API always returns json

Comment: Ah no worries, I figured it out, I was declaring the defaults option twice so it was being overwritten.